# Programmatically setting computed property of an itemController

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a template with the following code:

```
{{#each types itemController='type'}}
  <div class='col checkbox'>
    <label>
      {{input type='checkbox' checked=isSelected disabled=notAllowed}}
      <span {{bind-attr class='isSelected'}}>{{name}}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

`types` is set in `setupController`:

```
this.store.find('type').then(function(types){
  controller.set('types', types);   
});` 
//Having 2 other models here that I am setting and having an itemController for, exactly in the same fashion as types.
```

for the `ArrayController` which has the `itemController`.

NOTE: To clarify, I am using and setting 3 different models, which work pretty much in the same way as type, that makes this a bit more complicated.

Then the `itemController` itself:

```
App.TagController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isSelected: function(key, value){
    //bunch of code that does some stuff and returns true or false depending on value
  }.property()
});

App.TypeController = App.TagController.extend();
```

Now the problem: I have a `resetbutton` that should deselect all checkboxes and remove the `span classes`.
I would have thought about using an `action` (in the `ArrayController`) that sets all the `isSelected` properties to `false`, but I don't seem to be able to find a way to access and manually set that `itemController` computed property.
One thing I tried in the `ArrayController` is the following:

```
actions: {
  resetFilters: function(){
    this.get('types').forEach(function(type) {
       console.log(type.get('isSelected'));
       //type.set('isSelected', false);
    });
  }
}
```

But unfortunately this returns `undefined`. And using jQuery manually to remove the class and uncheck the checkbox seems to work the first instance, but the problem is, the computed property doesn't get updated and that messes things up.

Any idea how I can achieve what I want?
If anything is unclear let me know and I will do my best to clarify. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `controller.types`, this will not work with `itemController`. You should always be setting an array controller's `content` property.

The following should work:

```
controller.set('content', this.store.find('type'));
```

Then to set the `isSelected`:

```
controller.setEach('isSelected', false);
```

This assumes that controller is an instance of an `ArrayController` that has an `itemController` set in it's definition, e.g.

```
App.TypesController = Em.ArrayController.extend({itemController: 'type'});
```

Comment: Hmm, that is almost what I was thinking at one point, but my problem (what I should have clarified), I am displaying 3 different models in that array controller, so I am setting `type`, `style` and `categories`. How would that work with having 3 different models?

Comment: You need three different controllers in that case

Comment: Ok and the other controllers should then easily be able to access the other `ArrayControllers` (as well as the `isSelected` property), right?

Comment: Yes, you should use the "needs" mechanism to link controllers together

Answer (score -1):

`store.find` returns a PromiseArray, so it should be resolved first. You can set the types as follows in setupController:

```
this.store.find('type').then(function(types){
    controller.set('types', types);   
});
```

Or you can resolve types in the reset:

```
this.get('types').then(function(types) {
   types.forEach(function(type) {
       console.log(type.get('isSelected'));
   });
});
```

I would recommend the first one though.

Comment: Thank you for the two different solutions. The first, which seems to me like the more clean solution throws: `Assertion Failed: ArrayProxy expects an Array or Ember.ArrayProxy, but you passed object` and the reason seems to be the `each` in the template. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: The second solution still shows `undefined` unfortunately. Also I don't have `isSelected` explicitly defined in the `model`, just in the `itemController`. But even if I define it in the `model` itself it just shows `false` and not the value from the `itemController` property.

Comment: Does this.store.find('type') return an array?

Comment: Sorry, the first error was something stupid on my side (I defined `types` as an empty object in the controller instead of `null`) and has been fixed now. But `isSelected` still shows `undefined`.

Comment: types is an array of type models and type model does not have isSelected attribute.

Comment: That does make sense, but is there a way to access a computed property of an `itemController` for a specific `model`? I mean somehow ember must know that that specific computed property belongs to that model.

Comment: Inside an item controller, you can access to model and then compute the value of the computed property. That computed property is accessible in the template as well.

Comment: Yeah, but is there then any way to access that computed property outside of the `itemController` and outside of the `template`? Namely in the `ArrayController`?

Comment: You can do this in itemController `this.get('parentController.isSelected')`

Comment: Isn't that for the itemController to access the ArrayController? I am looking for the other way around.